# How to build g++ 10/C++20 on WSL2?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, wsl-2

I would like to try out the new features of C++20 on Windows 10 & WSL2.  Since my ubuntu on WSL2 was very old (16), I followed these [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/1317619/can-i-upgrade-my-existing-ubuntu-installation-in-wsl-from-16-04-to-18-04):

```
sudo apt update -y         # makes apt system itself up-to-date 
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y   # updates Ubuntu 18.04 packages to latest
sudo do-release-upgrade    # performs the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04
```

Midway thru these [directions for building g++ 10](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/04/building-gcc-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux/), I execute

```
contrib/download_prerequisites
```

and I get this error:

```
error: You must run this script in the top-level GCC source directory
```

The problem line of code seems to be

```
[ -e ./gcc/BASE-VER ]                                                         \
|| die "You must run this script in the top-level GCC source directory"
```

The problem is that while there is a gcc directory, there is no BASE-VER directory.

Is there a better set of instructions I should use? Is there a bug in this script?

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: Is ther a specific reason why you are building yourself? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192955/how-to-install-g-10-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Wow! I tried that before posting here and it did not work -- as other commenters noted it only went to g++-9. I tried it again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Being unfamiliar with WSL2 I cannot be sure, but this looks to me like...

`[ -e ./gcc/BASE-VER ]`  should be referring to `gcc/$BASE_VER` or some such.  Does it look like such a directory exists?

Also those apt commands updated you to version 18.04 of Ubuntu.  `do-release-upgrade` goes one version at a time, roughly speaking.  Assuming (?) you are on a `LTS` release (16.04) it will bump yu up one major version to the 18.04 version (major version numbers are even - a fact I only just noticed and I have been using Ubuntu since vit started....)

Comment: So if I am running 18.04 instead of 20, is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention I was suspicious of BASE-VER and I did a search and could find no such environment variable being created. Moreover, this is the only occurrence of the string "BASE-VER". Shucks!  When I look in the gcc directory I see mostly .c and .h files and only 4 directories with names of "ada", "cp", "po" & "config".

Comment: FWIIW https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/  And run `do-release-upgrade` again (have a book to read!) first.  As I said I am unfamiliar with WSL2 but it should be the same as a Linux

Comment: Where is do-release-upgrade?

Comment: Use command, from a terminal, `sudo do-release-upgrade` on a Ubuntu system to upgrade to the next version.  If you are on a LTS then it will upgrade to the next LTS.  try: `man do-release-upgrade`